# Performance: toggleClass takes too much time

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Created a dropdown, it is supposed to add or remove a class `select--open` when clicked but it seems to take too much time to execute the function.

it takes about `0.5secs` to open and `0.4secs` to close

```
var defaultSelect = self.find('> select');
self.on('click', function () {
   console.time('onClick');
   self.toggleClass('select--open');
   console.timeEnd('onClick')
});
```

Same as this.

```
self.on('click', function () {
console.time('onClick');
    if (self.hasClass('select--open')) {
         self.removeClass('select--open');
    } else {
         self.addClass('select--open');
    }
        console.timeEnd('onClick')
});
```

Both takes about the same time, I expect the time to be about `0.06 secs`. Can't tell what is making this time that amount of time.

Comment: why do you need to execute the functions so fast?

Comment: @madalinivascu it is a dropdown for mobile device, it feels draggy when it is slow

Comment: @madalinivascu I just realised there was an extra zero on the expected time, I have updated it now

Comment: Are you sure that class updates is the root cause of your issue? Probably, could it be the data filling?